# Error while connecting Mongodb Atlas using Dart

Tags: mongodb, flutter, dart, certificate, sslhandshakeexception

`HandshakeException`

This is how I'm trying to connect to the MongoDB:

```
class MongoDatabase {
  static connect() async {
   var db = await Db.create(MONGO_URL);
    await db.open();
    inspect(db);
    var status = db.serverStatus();`
    print(status);
    var collection = db.collection(COLLECTION_NAME);
    print(await collection.find().toList());****
  }
}
```

Which gives the following error:

```
E/flutter ( 2466): - HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: 
E/flutter ( 2466):  CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: certificate is not yet valid(handshake.cc:393))
E/flutter ( 2466): #0      ConnectionManager.open (package:mongo_dart/src/network/connection_manager.dart:153:9)
E/flutter ( 2466): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 2466): #1      Db.open (package:mongo_dart/src/database/db.dart:482:7)
E/flutter ( 2466): <asynchronous suspension>
```